# Use nvidia for cuda when desktop is using intel graphics

Tags: ubuntu, nvidia

I am running Pop!_OS 19.04 with nvidia drivers. When I boot into "NVIDIA Graphics" from the gnome menu everything works fine.

```
$ nvidia-smi 
Mon Sep  9 17:06:06 2019       
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| NVIDIA-SMI 435.21       Driver Version: 435.21       CUDA Version: 10.1     |
|-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+
| GPU  Name        Persistence-M| Bus-Id        Disp.A | Volatile Uncorr. ECC |
| Fan  Temp  Perf  Pwr:Usage/Cap|         Memory-Usage | GPU-Util  Compute M. |
|===============================+======================+======================|
|   0  GeForce GTX 105...  Off  | 00000000:01:00.0 Off |                  N/A |
| N/A   49C    P0    N/A /  N/A |    681MiB /  4040MiB |      3%      Default |
+-------------------------------+----------------------+----------------------+

+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Processes:                                                       GPU Memory |
|  GPU       PID   Type   Process name                             Usage      |
|=============================================================================|
|    0      1614      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                            72MiB |
|    0      2293      G   /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg                           150MiB |
|    0      2438      G   /usr/bin/gnome-shell                         385MiB |
+-----------------------------------------------------------------------------+
```

But I also want to use nvidia (for cuda) when I boot into "Intel Grapics". But then it says:

```
$ nvidia-smi 
NVIDIA-SMI has failed because it couldn't communicate with the NVIDIA driver. Make sure that the latest NVIDIA driver is installed and running.
```

I have additionally installed `nvidia-headless-no-dkms-435` but this did not solve the issue. Can I get both working, to switch into nvidia graphics and to get nvidia headless/cuda while using intel graphics?

Comment: It depends. Can your hardware (motherboard) do multi-monitor? If it can't use both cards simultaneously then it can't do what you want.

Comment: this should be possible on arch linux people can run 2 x sessions with different GPU using the same hardware ... I am thinking of moving to arch linux (I never was brave enough ^^).

Comment: It depends on hardware, not software.

Comment: yes same hardware that's what I said

Comment: The question is: Does your hardware supports it?

Comment: yes the answer is yes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible, thanks to this genius guy on askubuntu: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158036/avoid-using-nvidia-card-for-xorg-with-plasma

The solution is then replacing
/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d/11-nvidia-prime.conf by

```
# DO NOT EDIT. AUTOMATICALLY GENERATED BY gpu-manager

Section "OutputClass"
    Identifier "Nvidia Prime"
    MatchDriver "nvidia-drm"
    Driver "nvidia"
    Option "AllowEmptyInitialConfiguration"
    Option "IgnoreDisplayDevices" "CRT"
    # Option "PrimaryGPU" "Yes"   <<< commented out
    ModulePath "/x86_64-linux-gnu/nvidia/xorg"
EndSection
```

Comment: Note as of today, PopOS supports a switch from the Desktop where one option is "Computation" https://support.system76.com/articles/graphics-switch-ubuntu